# How to get a function to work within a DO statement in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql

I have a long and complex plpgsql function that creates a bunch of temporary tables nested within a while statement to get the optimal result. When the condition has been met I insert the result into an existing table, the function is far to long to post here but this is an example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_function(id_input integer, val_input numeric)
RETURNS VOID AS
$BODY$

DECLARE
   id_input numeric = $1;
   val_input numeric = $2;

BEGIN

WHILE test_val < 0
LOOP

CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table AS
SELECT a.existing_val - val_input AS new_val
FROM existing_table a
WHERE a.id = id_input;

test_val := (SELECT new_val FROM temp_table);

val_input := val_input + 1;

END LOOP;

INSERT INTO output_table (id, new_val)
SELECT a.id, a.new_val
FROM temp_table a;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The function works if I call it like this `SELECT test_function(1, 1000)` However I would like run this function on a table with 60,000+ rows, like this:

```
SELECT test_function(a.id, a.val_input)
FROM data_table a;
```

It works when I use a subset of the data_table, say 1000 rows. However when I run it on the full table (60,000+ rows) I get the following error `"AbortTransaction while in COMMIT state"`. After some reading I found out COMMITS, so in my case the inserts do not occur until the function has finished running which takes about 4 hours. So does anyone know what is going on?

As a workaround I tried nesting the function in a DO statement so the inserts are committed straight away:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
    r data_table%rowtype;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN
        SELECT * FROM data_table
    LOOP
    SELECT public.test_function(r.id, r.val_input);
    END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

However then I get the following error "ERROR: query has no destination for result data", which I guess means I need to rewrite the function to use PERFORM instead of SELECT. However I have not had any luck with this as yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: I apologize if I am oversimplifying your question, but wouldn't a select suffice? `SELECT public.test_function(r.id,r.val_input) FROM data_table r;`

Comment: I tried that, see the second block of code, however I got the commit error. Hence why I asked the question.

Comment: I see, my bad. Have you tried a `procedure` instead of a`function`? It is not returning anything ..

Comment: This is sort of unrelated to your question, but this seems like a poor strategy.  I know your function is simplified here, but couldn't you use a recursive CTE instead of all of those temp tables?  Creating thousands (millions?) of temp tables could lead to some nasty bloat issues in your catalog tables.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not interested in the function result, you should use

```
PERFORM public.test_function(r.id, r.val_input);
```

instead of

```
SELECT public.test_function(r.id, r.val_input);
```

The latter syntax would only work if you add `INTO some_variable` as a destination for the query result.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your suggestions. I ended up using Jim Jones's suggestion and converting the function to a procedure which allowed me to use COMMIT after I did the INSERT. I also followed Jeremy's suggestion and moved from temp tables to CTE's. This solved the problem for me.